# React application slow performance

Tags: reactjs, profiling

I am trying to make a application in react for rendering a tree like structure which can be expanded and collapsed on user input, although i have managed to get the app working as I want but the performance is quite slow. I am not sure if this is because of the nature of the application, the react component or my ignorance of the framework.

I have done a chrome profiling and here are the screenshots:

[image: Summary]

[image: Bottom Up]

[image: Call Tree]

Please if you can help me understand through this images what is the bottleneck and if/how it can be solved.

Source :

```
https://github.com/harsh-a1/react-skeleton/tree/tree
```

Component :

```
export function TreeComponent(props){

var instance = Object.create(React.Component.prototype)

var state = {
    previousSelected :{},
    onSelectCallback : props.onSelectCallback
}
instance.props = props;   
var toggle = function(){
    instance.setState(state.data)
}
instance.updateState = function(){
    instance.setState(Object.assign({},state))

}

if (!props.data){
    init(function(ous){
        state.data = ous;
        instance.setState(state)

    });
}
instance.render = function(){
    if (!state.data){return <div key = "dummy"></div>}

    return <ul key={"ul_"+state.data.id}>
        <Tree data={state.data} updateState={instance.updateState} state={state } />
        </ul>
}


return instance;


function Tree(props){
    var instance = Object.create(React.PureComponent.prototype)

    instance.render = function(){
        if (!props.data.children || props.data.children.length == 0){
            return (
                    <li key={"li_"+props.data.id}>
                    <LeafNode data={props.data} updateState = {props.updateState} state={props.state}  />                
                    </li>
            )
        }

        return  (            
                <li key={"li_"+props.data.id}><LeafNode data={props.data} updateState = {props.updateState} state={props.state} />
                <ul key = {"ul_"+props.data.id} style={props.data.showChildren?{"display":"inline"}:{"display":"none"}}>
                {
                    props.data.children.map(function(child){
                        return <Tree data={child} key={"tree_"+child.id} updateState = {props.updateState} state={props.state}  />
                    })                
                }
            </ul></li>
        )
    }
    return instance;
    function LeafNode(props){
        var instance = Object.create(React.PureComponent.prototype)
        instance.props = props;   

    /*    instance.shouldComponentUpdate = function(nextProps) {
            return (nextProps.data.showChildren !== this.props.data.showChildren);
        }
    */
        instance.componentDidMount= function(){
              console.log("yes")
        }

        instance.toggle = function(){

            props.data.showChildren = !props.data.showChildren;
            props.updateState();
        }

        instance.selected = function(){
            props.state.previousSelected.selected = false;
            props.data.selected = !props.data.selected;                
            props.state.previousSelected = props.data;
            props.updateState();
            props.state.onSelectCallback(Object.assign({},props.data));

        }

        instance.render = function(){
            var toggleImg = "";

            if ( props.data.children.length!=0){
                toggleImg = props.data.showChildren  ?expandIMG:collapseIMG; 
            }            
            return (
                    <div key={"div_"+props.data.id} >
                    <span key={"span_"+props.data.id} className="toggle"  >
                    <img key={"img_"+props.data.id} width="12" height="12" src={toggleImg} onClick={instance.toggle} />
                    </span>
                    <a key={"a_"+props.data.id} onClick = {instance.selected} style={props.data.selected? {color:"yellow"}:{color:"black"}}  >{props.data.name}</a>
                    </div>
            )
        }
        return instance        
    }   
}
}
```

Thanks

harsh

Comment: It looks like you are not using React how it is intended. It also looks like you are creating a new copy of the entire state on each interaction (Object.assign in TreeComponent), and hence re-rendering the entire component tree on every interaction. A first step of getting better performance would be to keep the expanded/collapsed state local to the sub-components.

Comment: i tried without assign object too it was same...is it rendering too much?? the screenshot of the summary statistic show most time spent in "scripting"....what does that mean?

Comment: I use react-free technologies to enhance performance

Comment: Here’s a great tutorial that can help improve loading and runtime performance of React SPAs: https://youtu.be/j8NJc60H294

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at best practices how to [create components](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) and [component lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) at `React` website. It is a good idea to follow them so it would be easier to identify problems later.

It is also worth looking at [react-virtualized](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized) components. There are a bunch of components that could be reused including list, grid, tree etc. Also look at their implementation since it is opensource.

Their [virtual list component](https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/#/components/List) resolved my issue with rendering 500+ items.

Comment: 500+ items?? My tree has more than 14000 nodes...it works fine on ~500 nodes.

Comment: react-virtualized can handle many thousands of rows. At which point a list of data becomes slow without windowing depends on the data, the way it's being rendered, the specs of the device being used to view it, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example with 1M+ nodes and good performance. The trick is to use local state and not render the hidden elements.

https://codesandbox.io/s/z6jr6zww4l

Answer (score 0):

Turns out The issue was that I was using the "development" build to check it....i switched to a production library and now it is running not to bad...still not as good as direct DOM but pretty close...although don't know how much it can scale...

Comment: Have not seen any performance issues running your hardcoded data for the Tree component. However, currently, it is only one component rendering. Btw, here is another performance related article that is worth looking at https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html.